# How to open the nav/tab when I click another button on the page?

Tags: javascript, css

I need help with one thing. I created a page where clicking on one button will scroll the page to the section with the side panel of buttons / bookmarks. I did it with a JS script, I would like the next action to be performed after clicking on the same button. I've already tried to do it using click() method, I've also tried to add "active" class to one of the tabs of the panel - unfortunately everything without positive result. Finally, maybe one of you will be able to help me.

Ultimately, I want the first link to switch the active section tab below. For better illustration I'm sending a picture of the pages.

JS file (The commented lines are the code I tried to use before):

```
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollBy({ top: 500, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    //const prescription = document.querySelector("#tab-title-prescription_tab");
    //prescription.classList.add("active");
    //document.getElementById("tab-title-prescription_tab").click();
}
```

HTML code:

```
<ul class="tabs wc-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="description_tab" id="tab-title-description" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-description"> <a href="#tab-description"> Opis </a></li>
    <li class="additional_information_tab" id="tab-title-additional_information" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-additional_information"> <a href="#tab-additional_information"> Dodatkowe informacje </a></li>
    <li class="reviews_tab" id="tab-title-reviews" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-reviews"> <a href="#tab-reviews"> Opinie (0) </a></li>
    <li class="prescription_tab_tab active" id="tab-title-prescription_tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-prescription_tab"> <a href="#tab-prescription_tab"> Recepta </a></li>
    <li class="survey_tab_tab" id="tab-title-survey_tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-survey_tab"> <a href="#tab-survey_tab"> Badania </a></li>
</ul>
```

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hk6r.jpg

First button:

```
<a onclick="scrollWin()" href="#tab-prescription_tab" class="button additional-button">Wybór szkieł</a>'
```

Comment: I think I have a solution using generators but need to  know `what do mean by next actions?` If you can explain that! I can create a code snippet!

Comment: @lost_in_magento The next action, just after scrolling down the page, is toggle the active tab. I marked it in the picture.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wrajesh/k9tcxozr/13/ It's adding `active` class name to the tab I used same code of yours

Comment: @lost_in_magento @lost_in_magento found the reason why your code doesn't work with me. I omitted such an important issue as changing the state of another selector. I have an additional div ```<div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--prescription_tab panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-prescription_tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-prescription_tab" style="display: none"``` with the display style entered: none. Is it possible to change it to a display: block when the indicated <li> is active ?

Comment: OK, case solved. I changed the styles with this code:  ```document.getElementById("tab-prescription_tab").style.display = "block";```. A thread to close. Thank you @lost_in_magento for your commitment, your answer brought me closer to my own! :)

Answer (score 0):

Anchor doesn't work ? Maybe you will make your button as link and set `href="#tab-prescription_tab"`

Comment: I forgot to add the button code. I just completed the description at the top. As for your advice, I've tried before. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.